# How to Fix trust Boundary Violation with modal request body

Tags: java, spring-boot, security

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ServiceRuleMgmtRequest implements Serializable {
    @NotNull
    private Integer costShareMapID;
    private Integer costShareAdminID;
    private Integer plCostShareID;
    private Integer serviceRuleID;
    private List<String> serviceRuleMgmtArray;
    private String serviceRule;
    private String serviceType;
    private String description;
    private String serviceCalMethod;
    private Double serviceAgeMin;
    private Double serviceAgeMax;
    private String serviceGender;
}
```

using this above modal to set the data using session.setAttribute but getting security error like trust boundary violation in it.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get existing Service Rule Management Details")
@PostMapping("/setDeductibleID")
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> setDeductibleID(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid @RequestBody ServiceRuleMgmtRequest serviceRuleMgmtRequest) {
    if (serviceRuleMgmtRequest == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(Collections.singletonMap("serviceRuleMsg", "Invalid ServiceRuleMgmtRequest"));
    }

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("serviceRuleMgmtRequest", serviceRuleMgmtRequest); //getting trust boundary violation here
    
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(Collections.singletonMap("serviceRuleMsg", "SUCCESS"));
}
```

I have tried using @valid still not able to solve the issue with trust boundary violation.Also tried with Encode.forJava to use it but it takes the string and we having it as a class.Also tried to use Encode.forJava in the setter of the modal by parsing it into integer then string but still not able to solve it.